# Google Cloud .NET Core publish Enable Services

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Trying to publish a .NET Core app to Google Cloud following this guide;
https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/

I get to this screen;
[image]
Clicking on "Enable the services" and it does nothing.  I have gone into the Google Console and enabled Google App Engine Flexible Environment.  What else needs to up enabled?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable these services:

1. App Engine Admin API
2. Google App Engine Flexible Environment

for you project.

You may use Google Cloud Console: [API & Services](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library)